# Hiding includes parent library

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-libraries

I am writing a shared library (call it MyLib) which depends on another library (call it ParentLib). The ParentLib has a few virtual functions which I am implementing in MyLib along with several other independent implementations.

```
// MyLib.h
#include <parentlib_library.h>

class Foo : public ClassinParent
{
   public:
      void DefinitionofParentLibFunction();
   private:
      // ...    
};
```

I was able to compile and generate the MyLib with no issues but when the MyLib is used by the application, I need to include the ParentLib_library.h to compile the code. 
One of my requirements is that the ParentLib should be completely hidden from the application. I am not sure of the next step to achieve this. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your declaration used in callback or implementation of interface from 3dparty lib - then no way. In all another cases I usually apply following 3 approaches.

1) Use aggregation. Declare ClassInParent as forward and use as member of Foo:

```
 class ClassInParent;//forward declare
 class Foo
 {
    ClassInParent* _inst; //use either pointer of reference to external
 public:
     void method_of_ClassInParent() //make facade for parent methods if needed
 }
```

2) Separate your class into interface (that is not depended on ClassInParent) and implementation (that is not expose via `#include`)

Your Foo.h:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   virtual void do_smth() = 0;
};
```

Your Foo.cpp:

```
#include <parentlib_library.h>
class FooImpl : public Foo, public ClassInParent
{
     void do_smth()
     {//implementation
```

3) Use templates. Instead of explicit inherience use template:

```
template <class T>
class Foo : public T
{
```

Later in your code `Foo<ClassInParent>`